# How to use update_metadata_accounts_v2 with invoke_signed?

Tags: anchor, metaplex, metadata

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/1596a05756aae9d62e91f192786e373ed7369196/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L589

I wondering 3 things.

1. How can i know invoke_signed's second parameter needs 3 accounts??

```
        &[
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            candy_machine_creator.to_account_info(),
        ],
```

2. And, Is this order important? For example, can I change order like this

```
        &[
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),               // 2
            candy_machine_creator.to_account_info(),               // 3
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(), // 1
        ],
```

3. What is need for seed? invoke_signed is need for PDA, right?

I try like this,

```
seed = &[&["metadata".as_ref(), 
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key().as_ref(),
            &[bump]]]
```

but fail with message

```
'Program failed to complete: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The metaplex documentation specifies the arguments and accounts needed for its instructions here: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions
2. No, order isn't important.
3. `invoke_signed()` is only needed when the signer for a transaction is a PDA because PDAs can't sign transactions on the client side like a normal wallet can. In your particular case `update_authority` is the signer for the transaction. If `update_authority` is a normal account then `invoke()` is all you need.